# После обновления locolStorage обнуляет состояние массива

Tags: reactjs

у меня есть такой массив с данными

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и по нажатию на кнопку все уходит сюда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

после чего я сохраняю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но после обновления страницы происходит это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот проект [тык](https://codesandbox.io/s/forked-lxrp84?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: Как данные с первой картинки попадают во вторую картинку? Третья понятна. Четвертая откуда? Удалите все скрины и добавьте код текчтом, что бы было понятно, что у вас происходиь в компонентах.

Comment: ссылка на код под четвертой картинкой

Answer (score 0):

добавить в localStorage это понятно, но негде нету что бы ты читал данные из localStorage.

когда обновляеш страницу, весь код запускается заного, сообственно в cart пустой массив

```
const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(localStorage.getItem('cart') ?? []);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, прошу вас, пишите ваши сообщения на русском языке.

Comment: @NNL993, извиняюсь это адрисовано мне, по сообшениям кидает сюда, вот только не пойму кому это адресовано ('про русский язык').

Comment: про русский язык я писал вам.

Comment: @ΝNL993 речь про грамматику или? я просто не вижу где я писал не на русском.

Comment: @ΝNL993 увидел, понял, не если что, тот кому я писал, меня отлично понимал, если речь идет о грамотном разложении всего по полочкам, то хорошо постараюсь в преть писать более в стиле документации, что бы править не пришлось. Просто это отнимает лишнее время и силы.

Comment: Этого требуют [правила веб-сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (Секция "Пишите как можно лучше"). Да, там указано, что грамматика не обязана быть идеальной, но у вас через слово приходится поправлять текст.

Comment: Согласен, главное что бы понятно было